# Unable to install anything in Lubuntu

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, sudo

I recently downloaded Lubuntu on my laptop, and I used a CD to install it.

My internet was not on.

After I got an internet connection, I tried using `sudo apt-get install`... to install various softwares such as `libreoffice` etc. but it just says package unavailable.

The Lubuntu Software Center doesn't have any of the softwares I need. They only have the very basic and the seemingly unnecessary.

It is slightly hard to do anything now, seeing as I can't download flash or java, or even update the version of the default Chrome installed.

How do I solve this problem?

EDIT:

Results of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
#deb cdrom:[Lubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1)]/ raring main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports mainrestricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
```

EDIT :

I tried following the answer to  [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)  question, but I only eventually get, after all the updation,

```
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is to show that this question is *not* duplicate.

Comment: Because your weren't connected, you probably only have your software sources set to the installation cd and not a network mirror. Can you edit your question with the result of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/620605/edit) your question and post the error messages.

Comment: What other software have you tried?  You need to use the package names exactly too.  libreoffice is not the correct name.  You can always try apt-cache search <package name> and you can see what the entries are.  Also, lubuntu does have a software center that is graphical I believe.

Comment: @JohnKirchner `libreoffice` is the name of a meta-package so that would work fine.

Comment: I also tried installing `openjdk-7-jdk` using the above method.

Comment: So the problem turned out to be that you installed 13.04, which in now end of life. You need to install either 15.04, 14.10 (supported only until July), 14.04, or 12.04. If you need lubuntu, lubuntu might only provide iso's for 15.04 and 14.04. See the answer linked above.

Comment: The problem is, downloading another OS takes a pretty long time. Is it possible for me to _not_ install another OS? Because pretty soon, I'm shifting to Windows, to I only need this OS for an interim period.